# power query breaks when table is deleted

Tags: powerquery

I have a query that reads data from table 1. however, some people when they use my sheet, they delete the whole table before they paste their extracted data, so power query breaks .. how to avoid that? .. because multiple people use this sheet and mostly they delete everything in the source tab before they paste their data.

Comment: Create a macro that defines the range each time new then kicks off the query refresh after.  Then people can just click a linked button to kickstart the process

Comment: I've already added a macro for people to refresh the queries once new source is added, how to create a macro to define a range please ?

Comment: I googled "how to create range name in VBA".  It seems like this was something people have asked before.  For example https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/

Comment: I've followed your steps exactly. now how do i add this named range to my query instead of table1

Comment: I have not provided any steps. That is not my website. If the website is not clear, perhaps google for another one. Best of luck